# URL slug with Scandinavian letters

Tags: php, mysql, string

I found a very neat script that converts an amount of text into a URL slug (see point 3). It's working like a charm until the text contains one of these letters: ÆØÅ. If one of these letters appears then $tag becomes blank (nothing is inserted in MySQL afterwards).

Why is this, and how should I fix it? I would love if possible the letters would convert like this: Æ>ae - Ø>oe - Å>AA

(1) My HTML charset is set to

```
charset="iso-8859-1"
```

(2) The field's collation in my MySQL phpmyadmin is set to

```
utf8_danish_ci
```

(3) This is how my code looks like:

```
// replace non letter or digits by -
$tag = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $tag);

// trim
$tag = trim($tag, '-');

// transliterate
$tag = iconv('iso-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $tag);

// lowercase
$tag = strtolower($tag);

// remove unwanted characters
$tag = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $tag);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp in the last line of your code is filtering these characters out. The `\w` matches any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and the Scandinavian characters do not fall into this range.

You mentioned you would like to convert those characters, you can do that at the beginning with a simple `str_replace` like this:

**Update: we also need to move the iconv**

```
// transliterate
$tag = iconv('iso-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $tag);

$tag = str_replace(array('Æ', 'Ø', 'Å'), array('ae', 'oe', 'AA'), $tag);

// replace non letter or digits by -
$tag = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $tag);

// trim
$tag = trim($tag, '-');

// lowercase
$tag = strtolower($tag);

// remove unwanted characters
$tag = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $tag);
```

Comment: Hello, when I use your str_replace() function, then the $tag becomes empty. Why is this? Should I change the charset?

Comment: @amadeo - very sorry! There was a mistake in my code! I'm having a bad code day. Updated the code in the answer.

Comment: No problem hehe, I just appreciate the help! Anyway, the code still doesn't work. It still "emptys" $tag.

Comment: That's really strange, because I created a test script with the code above and set `$tag = 'testing ÆØÅ';` and then `echo` $tag at the end. When I run it, it gives me this output: `testing-aeoeaa`

Comment: Could the iconv() function cause the problem?

Comment: Could you paste the string you are testing the function with in a comment? I can try to debug

Comment: It's actually any string containing any of those three letters :-/. The string is created by a form, where I can create this category-name along with a URL-slug. For example if I enter "Øl" then the slug would be "oel".

Comment: Ok, cool - I put together a [test](https://gist.github.com/madebydavid/11289117) - got it working if I move the iconv. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot - it works now. I really appreciate the help!! Good people are to be found in this world!